# GAE Generating client library methods or constructors

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been playing around with GAE on an android and its backend. I managed to get it working in Eclipse with the google plug in. I created a simple Java POJO, generated its cloud backend, and its respective cloud endpoint client library.

I tried to add a constructor and some utility methods to the POJO but they were not included in the client library, so the android class could not use those methods.

Is this intended? or have I missed something?

Edit (example code):

For example, the following class in the app engine:

```
public class MessageCodes {
public static final String CODE_OK = "0000";
public static final String CODE_ERROR = "0001";

private String code;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public boolean isOk(){
    if( code.equals(CODE_OK))
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

The method "isOK()" does not appear on the android frontend.

Thanks

Comment: Did you generate a new client library after editing the POJO?  Please show some relevant lines from the client library so that we have a concrete example to discuss.